# Get absolute url using routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This should be simple. I want to get an absolute Uri given the controller, action and other routevalues. In other words I want to do what Html.ActionLink does but without the anchor and I want to do it in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate link URLs with [UrlHelper.Action()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx). Your controllers already have this as property Url.

```
Url.Action("Logout", "AccountController")
```

Comment: Great. The UrlHelper needed a RequestContext which I got from ControllerContext.

Comment: You don't have to specify AccountController as aAccount would suffice, as in 'Url.Action("Logout", "Account")'

Answer (score 4):

When I tried to use UrlHelper(string action, string controller) I was still getting a relative path.

So to generate the full url I used a Uri and passed the Uri of the Request as the baseUri.

ie:

---

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
var routeUri = new Uri(Request.Url, urlHelper.Action("action", "controller"));
return routeUri.AbsoluteUri;
```